# Eclipse GEF - Snap to Grid not working

Tags: eclipse-rcp, jface, eclipse-gef

I am trying to use the "Snap to Grid" function for a GEF viewer. I am following the tutorial at [this site](https://www.vainolo.com/2011/09/04/creating-an-opm-gef-editor-%E2%80%93-part-18-snapping-to-grid-and-to-geometry/). The tutorial essentially talks about installing necessary edit policies and overriding the `getAdapter` method like below:

```
@Override
public Object getAdapter(Class key) {
    System.out.println("snapping..." + key);
    if (key == SnapToHelper.class) {
        List<SnapToHelper> helpers = new ArrayList<SnapToHelper>();
        if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(getViewer().getProperty(
                SnapToGeometry.PROPERTY_SNAP_ENABLED))) {
            helpers.add(new SnapToGeometry(this));
        }
        if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(getViewer().getProperty(
                SnapToGrid.PROPERTY_GRID_ENABLED))) {
            helpers.add(new SnapToGrid(this));
        }
        if (helpers.size() == 0) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return new CompoundSnapToHelper(
                    helpers.toArray(new SnapToHelper[0]));
        }
    }
    return super.getAdapter(key);
}
```

However during runtime, the `getAdapter` method is never called with a `SnapToHelper` instance which I confirmed by putting a `println` method.
am I missing something?

Comment: Did you install the edit policy? Did you add the button to the toolbar to activate this?

Comment: Yes I installed edit policies on the root editpart and the node editpart

Comment: I had some issues adding the button to toolbar. Hence added the action to the context menu

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I learnt that I had made a trivial mistake which took me several days to figure out. The code snippet of `createFigure` method for a typical `TopEditPart` is as follows:

```
protected IFigure createFigure() {
    Figure f = new FreeformLayer();
    f.setLayoutManager(new FreeformLayout());

    f.setBorder(new MarginBorder(1));
    // Create a layout for the graphical screen
    f.setOpaque(true);
    helpers = new ArrayList<SnapToHelper>();
    helpers.add(new SnapToGrid(this));
    CompoundSnapToHelper h = new CompoundSnapToHelper(
            helpers.toArray(new SnapToHelper[0]));

    return f;
}
```

In the above method, using `f.setOpaque(true);` had hidden the grid all this while and had cost me several days to figure out. I have now changed it to `f.setOpaque(false);` and now I am able to see the grid. Hope many could save time because of this answer.